# UPDATE doesn't allow to INSERT null in FK field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have a SQL Server database and in a table there's a lookup column which is a "nullable FK" linked to a master table.

There's a data import process in which we fetch data from `table01_staging` into `table01`. This is the `UPDATE` statement which is failing (if CarrierID is null) -

```
DECLARE @code as nvarchar(10); SET @code = 'xyz';
UPDATE table01 
SET CarrierID = t2.CarrierID
FROM table01 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table01_staging AS t2 ON t1.Code = @code;
WHERE t1.Code = @code;
```

It goes fine if the `CarrierID` is not null. In fact I can successfully execute:

```
UPDATE table01 
SET CarrierID = null 
WHERE t1.Code = 'xyz';
```

So setting null is not the problem but it doesn't work when its updated from the staging table which has a null value. How can I make it right?

> Error : The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_table01_MasterCarrier`. The conflict occurred in database `table01`, table `dbo.MasterCarrier`, column `ID`.

**> EDIT 02: DONE!.** Updated the first SQL to show my variable usage - which I believe was the culprit. Correcting the JOIN operation as follows with a COLLATion conversion error fix makes it work -

```
DECLARE @code as nvarchar(10); SET @code = 'xyz';
UPDATE table01 
SET CarrierID = t2.CarrierID
FROM table01 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table01_staging AS t2 ON t1.Code = t2.code COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE t1.Code = @code;
```

Thank you all, esp. Zhang. I deserve a -1 for not being able to understand the JOIN clause properly :-)

Comment: Do you have null ID values (not CarrierID)?

Comment: The error message listed in the (currently) first comment does not match the code listed. What is "database table01"? What or where is table "dbo.MasterCarrier"?

Comment: Looking just at the code, this "smells" like a problem involving an underlying view or trigger. Is table01 a view? Are there any triggers on the updated table(s)?

Comment: maybe t2.CarrierID is not NULL but it is something that violates your FK?

Comment: No null entry possible in MasterCarrier. Phillip, pls try to infer the actual issue - error comes in the first UPDATE and not in the second one. No other things involved, two simple tables. FLICKR - if it violates anything how come the second UPDATE executes successfully? I believe it to be an UPDATE statement issue.

Comment: @HemantTank Update your question - it's not clear. Right now it sounds like NULLs are causing trouble. But then you say that update to NULLs succeeds. Select what `update` with join returns as `t2.CarrierID`. Why are you saying that update does not allow null? It does as your second update demonstrates.

Comment: Ivan I've updated it. And Your question is same as mine - if the second one works why doesn't the first one! In both case CarrierID value is null but only the first one fails.

Comment: @Hemant your question is _"Why FK  column **does not allow NULLs**"_,  but last paragraph of your question is _"How can't you all understand that it **does allow NULLs**"_.

Comment: @Ivan, I didn't get you. The second UPDATE works, the first fails - why? Its a simple nullable column with FK constraint.

Comment: @Hemant, your question is still _"why FK column does not allow NULL"_. It does. You tested it yourself. So what your update statement is trying to put into that column? It's not NULL. Find out that value `update` is attempting to write.

Comment: Ivan, I've confirmed it for you and it is NULL (not to be confused with blank or special char).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does table01_staging have the same Foreign Key Constraint on CarrierID?

If not, check whether there are some CarrierID not existing in MasterCarrier table.

```
select * from table01_staging t 
 where not exists (select 1 from MasterCarrier m where m.ID = t.CarrierID)
```

!!UPDATE!!

I created the sample table and data. It worked without any issue.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].MasterCarrier(
      [id] [int] IDENTITY NOT  NULL,
      [NAME] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mastertable]  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
      [id] ASC
)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table01](
      [id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [CarrierID] [int] NULL,
      [Code] [varchar](10) NULL
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].table01  WITH CHECK  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table01_MasterCarrier] FOREIGN KEY([CarrierID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MasterCarrier] ([id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].table01 CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table01_MasterCarrier]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table01_staging](
      [id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [CarrierID] [int] NULL,
      [Code] [varchar](10) NULL
) 
GO

--Insert sample data
INSERT INTO MasterCarrier (NAME)  VALUES ('carrier');
INSERT INTO table01 (id, CarrierID, Code) VALUES (1, 1, 'abc'), (2,  NULL, 'abc'),(3, 1, 'ddd');
INSERT INTO table01_staging (id, CarrierID, Code) VALUES (1, 1, 'abc'), (2,  NULL, 'abc'),(3, 1, 'ddd');


UPDATE table01
SET CarrierID=t2.CarrierID
FROM table01 AS t1
INNER JOIN table01_staging AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Code='abc'
```

> It gets (2 rows affected) message.

Comment: Yes, there're a few NULL values in table01_staging.CarrierID and the MasterCarrier table doesn't have any NULL entries. But table01_staging.CarrierID is a nullable FK to the MasterCarrier table. And as said the second UPDATE statement works fine.

Comment: NULL value is ok. It's not because of NULL value in the staging table. Check other values.

Comment: Believe me I've tested all - its only because of the CarrierID field and that also only for the first UPDATE. Also the error points to that field.  Its like it won't allow  using JOIN!

Comment: Thanks. I tried your script and got clues from it which helped my dig out the actual issue which was due to usage of variable in the JOIN operation.  Pls see Edit 02.